# Android Media Player on Completion listener not working as expected

Tags: android

I have a Media Player runnning in a background service. MP3 files are setn ovewr TCP from a server on my desktop. When debugging the app the songs are sent and received. The seleciton of songs is structured over three activities. 
Album list (list view) activity takes you to a song list (list view) activity.
you select songs by selecting a checkbox and on selection clicking a play button. 
Play button binds to service and song is requested over tcp. All songs are added to storage on phone. Here is the method that receives the byte[] setn over tcp (thisis form within myMediaPlayer class:

```
public void AddSong(byte[] toParse, String songName)
        {
            File cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MusicStreamCache");
            if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();

            File temp = new File(cacheDir, songName);
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                fos.write(toParse);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            songs.add(temp);
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && !isPaused)
            {
                MediaPlay();
            }

        }

        public void AddSong(File filein)
        {
            filein.deleteOnExit();
            songs.add(filein);
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && !isPaused && CurrentSong == 0)
            {
                MediaPlay();
            }
        }

        public void MediaPlay()
        {
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && CurrentSong <= songs.size())
            {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                try{
                      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(songs.get(CurrentSong));
                      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

                      mediaPlayer.prepare();
                      int length = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                      mediaPlayer.start();
                      if(CurrentSong <= songs.size())
                      {
                           CurrentSong ++;   
                      }

                    }
                catch(Exception err)
                {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    String error = err.getMessage();
                }

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

            }
        }

        OnCompletionListener completionListener = new OnCompletionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(CurrentSong <= songs.size())
                {
                    MediaPlay();
                }

            }

         };
```

When the phone is hooked up to my desktop and I am debugging the app everything works as expected. I can add one song from an album and it will download and play. I can add several songs from an album ( or all songs) and they will download and play one after the other. I can select songs from several different albums and they will all download one after the other and play in sequence i.e. the on completion listener is working as expected.

The problem occurs when I select to run my app from Eclipse (without debugging) and then detach from the desktop (to test when WiFi signal is weak or at different places around the house).If I select a song it downloads and plays fine. However if I select more than one song the first song plays fine but further songs will not play. They are downloading as if I select a new song when the first song has stopped playing the next song in the list on downloaded songs plays and the newly selected song downloads but does not play., I cant seem to work out why this is happening?

As I am not having these problems when I am debugging. I am wondering if my service is loosing focus when it is not plugged into the desktop? Or am I missing something obvious?? I have added a partial wake lock to my media player but his doesn't seem to alleviate the problem?? Any tips would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you resetting your media player when the song stops?

Comment: I am resetting in the on completion listener which works when debugging but not when just running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:-)

It seems that having a media player class containing a media player object and some custom methods was stopping the onCompletionListener from working (except for when debugging). To work around this my service now implements OnCompletionListener and a Media Player object is created directly in the service. In the OnComplete metod I release the current media player and create a new one. It all works as expected.

If anyone can shed light on why my original solution was not working I would like to better understand what I was doing wrong in the first place!!!

Comment: Old but as a tip, rather than release, reset.